# Cannot assign value of type Binding<XXX> to type XXX

Tags: swiftui, combine

I know how to fix this error, but my fix leads to another error.

The initial problem is the following

```
@Binding var report: Report

init(property: Property, report: Binding<Report>, saveAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.property = property
    self.report = report // cannot assign value of type Binding<Report> to type Report
    self.data = SpacesData(property: property, report: report)
    self.saveAction = saveAction
}
```

If I change to the following

```
var report: Binding<Report>

init(property: Property, report: Binding<Report>, saveAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.property = property
    self.report = report
    self.data = SpacesData(property: property, report: report)
    self.saveAction = saveAction
}
```

The error goes away but I can no longer call methods on report. So for instance the following

```
let image = report.loadCoverImage(for: property)
```

throws the error

> Dynamic key path member lookup cannot refer to instance method
> 'loadCoverImage(for:)'

Comment: In your first block of code do `self._report = report`, which assigns the argument value of `Binding<Report>` type to the actual Binding property wrapper

Comment: Thanks @NewDev would you like to put that as an official answer and I will accept it? Would be great to know what just happen. To me that underscore is random as hell. Black magic.

Comment: Yeah, it's a compiler-synthesized property that contains the property wrapper type. The Swift documentation touches on it [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617). I would have provided it as an answer, but it's technically a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973959/swiftui-how-to-implement-a-custom-init-with-binding-variables