# Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties in SwiftUI Project?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code in my SwiftUI code:

```
@Binding var tabSelection: Int

    
init() {

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear; UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
      
}
```

But when I try to compile my code, I get this error:

[image]

If I remove this code, I can successfully compile my app:

```
init() {

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear; UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
      
}
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you created a `View`, since it's a `struct`, Xcode synthesizes initializers for you. This means that you pass a `Binding` in as a parameter and it automatically gets set for you.

In this case, since you've definite your own `init`, you also have to take that `Binding` parameter and initialize your own property.

```
struct MyView : View {
    @Binding var tabSelection: Int
    
    init(tabSelection: Binding<Int>) {
        _tabSelection = tabSelection //<-- Here (have to use the underscore because of the `@Binding` -- see the link later in the post
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear; UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

See also: [SwiftUI: How to implement a custom init with @Binding variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973959/swiftui-how-to-implement-a-custom-init-with-binding-variables)