# pass a binding variable to a function of a class in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have a class with a function like this

```
class someClass {

func someWorkNeedToDo(var1: String) {

@Binding var action: Bool

}
```

now i want to pass a Binded Boolean to this function so that i can control the navigation. what is the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Already answered here: [SwiftUI: How to implement a custom init with @Binding variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973959/swiftui-how-to-implement-a-custom-init-with-binding-variables)